# subset variables in a dataset independently using dplyr

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

I would like to replicate the following using dplyr.

```
set.seed(123)
my_data <- data.frame( time = c(4:13, 4:13),
                       var1 = rep(c("a", "b"), each=10), 
                       var2 = rnorm(20))

my_data_new <- with(my_data,
                      data.frame ( time = time[var1 =="a"], 
                                  var2a = var2[var1 == "a"], 
                                  var2b = var2[var1 == "b"]))
```

I have tried similar syntax with transmute() and get the following error message

```
Error: wrong result size (10), expected 20 or 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `do` but it is not very elegant ie. `my_data %>% do(data.frame( time=.$time[.$var1=='a'], var2a=.$var2[.$var1=='a'], var2b=.$var2[.$var1=='b']))`

Comment: Seems like you're really using the wrong tool. You are really reshaping your data. Thus `melt()/cast()` from `reshape2` or `gather()/spread()` from `tidyr` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
res <- spread(my_data, var1, var2)
colnames(res) <- colnames(my_data_new)
identical(res, my_data_new)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or you can use `rename` from `dplyr` to change the column names (as suggested by @Richard Scriven)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
spread(my_data, var1, var2)%>%
                        rename(var2a=a, var2b=b)
```

Comment: You could be really `dplyr`-y and do `%>% rename(var2a = a, var2b = b)` after `spread`